# Facing: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'DynamicServerError' of 'serverHooks' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, package

I am facing the above error in a Nextjs app with TypeScript, and it is on the line of my react component that you can find [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-enigma-pin-lock). This is the very first package I've created and although by trial and error I've at last tested this package in a similar environment, in an vite and TypeScript environment and it was successful.

But I am not able to do the same in this Nextjs app where I want to use it.

The full error in terminal:

```
Attempted import error: 'react-enigma-pin-lock' does not contain a default export (imported as 'EnigmaPinLock').

Import trace for requested module:

./src/app/page.tsx

- warn Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload due to a runtime error.

Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at page.tsx:8.
```

In the Error screen:
[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKhXn.png)
Now, I know that this is supposed to be an import-export related error, but the package indeed exports the component as Default.

`export default EnigmaPinLock;`

If there is a need of changing anything in the project to suppress this error please tell me as I am new to the package making in react.
Please Help a brother out:)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-enigma-pin-lock

As per the documentation mentioned above the default import type should be:

```
import EnigmaPatternLock from "react-enigma-pin-lock";
```

Comment: Yes, and it is my brother

Comment: But it still doesn't work in NextJS app

Comment: The same I tested with a react vite app and it seems to work perfectly, you can see it in the screenshots section in the NPM package link above.

Comment: I also tried to create a local component and use it and it still gives the same error